# Symfony form to create a collection of entities sharing inputs

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.2

I need to make a form to create a collection of the same entity, but I do not want to repeat all fields for each entry of the collection (only fields which will have different values).

Imagine a `Product` entity:

```php
class Product
{
    private $category;
    private $name;
    private $price;
}
```

I would like a form to create multiple `Product` entities of the same `category` at the same time.
So the form should have one `category` field, and a collection of `name` and `price`.

My form will look something like:

```php
class ProductCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('category')
            ->add('products', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => ProductType::class,
                'allow_add'  => true,
                'mapped'     => false,
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ));
    }
}

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('price')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Anyone know if there is a way to automatically fill all entities in the collection type with the parent fields? (only `category` in this example)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by having form(s) for the Product(s) which do not require a value for the category member. Then create a single unmapped field to receive a category value. Once back in the controller after submission, apply the unmapped category value to each of the Product entities, and then process/persist/etc.

Checkout the [Symfony Forms page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes), search for "mapped" and you'll see how to add an unmapped field to a form.

Comment: This is a very basic example I am providing, but in my real use case this not concern only one field and I want to keep advantage of the constraints I put on my entity for all fields. I hoped there was something provided by symfony intended for this use case.

Comment: You could instantiate an extra Product and make it's form only require the category field. Now you get all of the Product::category's contraints a la Doctrine, Symfony forms, etc.

"Use one form field for a set of objects" is a fairly off-the-beaten-path use case. Leverage what you can, but you've got to expect a compromise and some extra work.